# how to assign one value to a list of Objects in an efficient way in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to assign one value to a list of objects in Matlab without using a for-loop (In order to increase efficiency)

Basically this works:

```
for i=1:Nr_of_Objects
    Objectlist(i,1).weight=0.2
end
```

But I would like something like this:

```
Objectlist(:,1).weight=0.2
```

Which is not working. I get this error:

**Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 5 results.**

Writing an array to the right hand side is also not working.
I`m not very familiar with object oriented programming in Matlab, so I would be happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your looking for the [`deal`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function:

```
S(1,1).a = 1
S(2,1).a = 2
S(1,2).a = 3

[S(:,1).a] = deal(4)
```

Now `S(1,1).a` and `S(2,1).a` equal to `4`.

In matlab you can concatenate several output in one array using `[]`. And `deal(X)` copies the single input to all the requested outputs.

So in your case:

```
[Objectlist(:,1).weight] = deal(0.2)
```

Should work.

Noticed that I'm not sure that it will be faster than the for loop since I don't know how the `deal` function is implemented.

**EDIT: Benchmark**

```
n = 1000000;
[S(1:n,1).a] = deal(1);

tic
for ii=1:n
    S(ii,1).a = 2;
end
toc

% Elapsed time is 3.481088 seconds

tic
[S(1:n,1).a] = deal(2);
toc

% Elapsed time is 0.472028 seconds
```

Or with `timeit`

```
n = 1000000;
[S(1:n,1).a] = deal(1);

g = @() func1(S,n);
h = @() func2(S,n);

timeit(g)
% ans = 3.67
timeit(h)
% ans = 0.41

function func1(S,n)
    for ii=1:n
        S(ii,1).a = 2;
    end
end


function func2(S,n)
    [S(1:n,1).a] = deal(2);
end
```

So it seems that using the `deal` function reduce the computational time.

Comment: tic/toc isn't always reliable in my experience, try changing the benchmark order (first with deal, second with loop) and see if result is consistent. There is also the [timeit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) function and the run with profiling option though.

Comment: @Mefitico If the memory is already preallocated, the order should not change the computational time. I've added the timeit version.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me. Even though my code is faster using for loop then the deal function. I dont now, maybe it depends on the matlab version (R2018b) I`m using.

Comment: I used the "Live Editor" online for the benchmark. If you only have one column in your structure, you could also be interested by a [table](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html).

Comment: I think it makes sense that `deal` reduces execution time: it assigns all the values in one operation; the loop is going to have to copy the "header" stuff for the object array each time one of its values is changed, even if it doesn't have to copy any of the underlying primitive data held in the fields. I'm guessing that doing the deal lets you avoid all those temporary copies of the intermediate object array state and their associated GC.